# Remove empty space Drupal

Tags: drupal, responsive-design, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I have a problem with a theme in drupal. The documentation says it is responsive but when I check it on a mobile, although it resizes everything, it also creates an empty space on the right side of the page. I really don't understand why.

http://nexus.techsaran.com/ This is a link for the demo of the theme when you use the emulator in chrome to see it like if you were on a mobile it creates the empty space and it also does it when you check the link directly from your phone

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This caused by your adsense div.[image]

Try to generate responsive ads from your adsense account or add this code to your css :

```
.adsense {
   width: 100% !important;
}
```